# Восстановить Wiki в мак ос

Tags: mac

Раньше в мак ос была программа сервер с встроеным движком вики. Использовалась для своих заметок. В новой версии ее выпилили. Где найти файлы, чтобы восстановить контент?

Comment: Вы ведете речь о [macOS Server](https://www.apple.com/lae/macos/server)? "Где найти файлы, чтобы восстановить контент?" — в Вашей резервной копии?

Comment: А по какому пути искать кто-нибудь знает? Где должен лежать каталог с файлами вики.